# Network Analysis problem

Tags: passive-networks, linear

[image]

I am not able to get the concept of how to calculate the output voltage.
What I did was- I assumed the network N as such-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqflQ9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now added two networks-

[image: schematic]

So if I assume R2/(R1+R2)=x. Then Vo=x*(V1+V2)/2.
Accordingly from the question the value of x is 3.Thus the answer of Ques 1 is 0 and the answer of ques 2 is 3.
Is my analysis right?
If possible can you point out to me any reading material for these kind of problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this right on the second attempt

[image]

Of course I made a mistake in the ending, I promise I will transpose all this to mathjax.

It seems that:

$$
V_u = \frac{\alpha}{2}(V_1+V_2)
$$
So:
$$
\alpha = 2\frac{V_u}{V_1+V_2}=2\frac{6}{4}=3
$$
Finally:
$$
\text{Q1: } V_u = 0V\\
\text{Q2: } V_u = 3V
$$

Comment: Q2. answer is 3volts.

Comment: That's the answer you calculated...

Comment: Vu=3*(7-5)/2=3 volts

Comment: Ok, you are perfectly right. Sorry for the mess up, I hope I helped you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Because the networks are linear you can apply the superposition theorem. Let each network have an output x to an input of 1V. The output to an arbitrary input is then:
$$V_o = V_i x$$
Applying the superposition theorem for the two sources:
$$V = ( V_1 + V_2 ) x$$
Taking into account that there are no internal sources in the networks.
For the input of 1V and 3V one gets
$$4x = 6 \rightarrow x = 1.5$$
You can then calculate the voltages.

Comment: I find your notation a bit misleading. \$V_i\$ is a pure number, maybe using something like \$A\$ would have been better. Plus, a linear network has a transfer function of the form \$V_o=AV_i+B\$.

Comment: @Vladimir Cravero, should the 'B' be there for a linear network? It wouldn't be for a linear system.

Comment: 'B' will not be there for a linear network as it won't satify the property of "Superposition".

Comment: I think as @VladimirCravero says the B CAN be there for a linear system, which is why this problem only makes sense if there are no internal sources. Since that's not stated in the original post the problem can't be solved unless you assume that's the case.

Comment: I don't feel this answer nor mine are right. Applying superposition is fine, but output voltage is **not** the sum of the outputs of the two networks, since they are in parallel and not in series. When you use superp. you need to take into account the fact that the network which is off has output = 0, thus your nets are fighting as two parallel voltage sources would.

Comment: @VladimirCravero According to me there can be no "B" because the network is linear. Voltage V1(when you short V2) and V2 (when you short V1) sees the same circuit. Hence they will have V0=AV1 (when V2 is shorted)
V0=AV2 (when V1 is shorted).
Then applying superposition- Vo=A(V1+V2).

Comment: I think it is assumed in the question that there are no internal sources, if there were, then the question would be incomplete.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. Have a look at my new answer and please downvote the old one.

Comment: You can apply the superposition theorem because the networks are identical. You are right that the second network will appear in parallel, but you can treat both networks as a single linear system.